# How to detect an error from SQL Server in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, silverlight

I'm using Silverlight and I'm trying to get the ID for my new user from my database.

This is how I'm doing it:

```
Random r = new Random();
int id = r.Next(1000,2000) * 10;

query = "SELECT MAX(ParticipantID) FROM Participant";
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query, SqlCon);

try
{
    SqlCon.Open();
    id = (int)cmd2.ExecuteScalar();
}
catch { logger.Error("Add: sqlConnectionError"); }
finally { SqlCon.Close(); }
```

My problem is that sometimes I get the the `id` from the random math and not from my database.

The problem will appear in the `SqlCon.Open();` or in `id = (int)cmd2.ExecuteScalar();` line?

Is there a way that if it's not getting the id from the database it will try again?

Let's say try 100 time until the id is different then before?

How can I do it? I can not do it recursively.

Is there a way with a loop?

Comment: The problem is your whole approach. If you want an ID that is unique in the table/database, you should ask the database engine to provide one for you.

Comment: maybe it will work but i need to fix this code and not to write new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i get the the "id" from the random math and not from my DB

It is because you're generating it randomly using this

```
int id = r.Next(1000,2000) * 10;
```

Why to initialize it with `Random` in first place? initialize it with `0`.

```
int id = 0;
for (int i =0; i<100; i++)
{
     id = ...;//Get value from DB
    if(IsValidId(id))//validate the ID
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

However it sounds like you should be using `Auto-Increment` column; that's the better option if you're just looking for uniqueness.

Comment: i know that i generate  it with math random, i cannot do it with 0 because i have user 0 i need all the time new users but from 0-infinity with no holes. i cannot change the DB it's not mine. but i think it will work what your are saying. Thx